# How to write a program that can download and install many packages (c++)?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

**My specific case**:

I am trying to implement a maze solver in c++ that takes in a grayscale picture and outputs the same picture with the solved path.  I have looked online and found that I should use OpenCV which requires other packages as well. I want the user of my program to be able to run the program, which checks if these packages are already installed.  If the required packages are not installed, I want to be able to install these programs on the machine (Linux).  The rest of my program will use these packages to solve the maze.

**General Case**:

How can I create a program that when executed, installs required packages for the program to be used later? Is this possible? What is this called (if it exists) so I can read about it? And finally, would this be incredibly difficult for a team of first year c++ students?

Thank you for your responses, I have tried to look for an answer myself but cannot find one.

Comment: Why would you want to? Surely listing the requirements for what you need is sufficient - in suitable for such as `yum install A B C D E F`?

Comment: Most Linux-based distributions have OpenCV in their software repositories, and also have full dependency tracking. So if you install the OpenCV development package then all the needed packages will be installed automatically.

Comment: Of if you really NEED to do this automatically, write something that understands what distro it is and runs the relevant `yum/apt-get/rpm install`

Comment: What you are looking for is called configuration management (among other things). There are plenty of tools for that, so there should be no need to reinvent the wheel. Consider searching the internet for Ansible, Chef, Puppet, and SaltStack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, this problem is typically solved by what is known as a package manager.

Different distributions employ different package managers. For example, Debian based distributions utilize Debian packages (`.deb` files). RedHat and it's child project Fedora utilize RPM packages (`.rpm` files). Depending on your distribution you would then create the appropriate package for your project and list it's dependencies in the package's control file.

If you are using a Debian based distribution, I would highly recommend [Aptly](http://www.aptly.info/). It will allow you to create local repos, mirror existing repos, and host your own repo on Amazon's S3.

I should also mention [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) for this. Docker can also be thought of as a package manager of sorts. It basically allows your application to carry its operating system configuration with it, which will allow you to deploy the app to almost anywhere docker will run. There could be some limitations if you are tied to camera hardware, but it's definitely worth consideration. Also, with [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) you can freely deploy it to all of your classmates/students machines as well.

Hope that helps!